# New Django middleware not getting called

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, memcached, django-middleware

I am quite new to web development. I am working on a website hosted on amazon ec2 server. The site is in python using django framework. I am using memcached to cache some client information. My site and caching works on local machine but not on the EC2 server. I checked memcached server and found out that it was not able to set the keys. Is there something I might need to change in settings.py so that keys are set appropriately on the server or something else that I might be missing.

EDIT: Found out the problem. I added a new middleware for setting keys in the memcache. That is not getting called. It works perfectly on the local machine. On the server I am using gunicorn as the app server and nginx as the reverse proxy. Can any of these cause the problems. Also I tried to reload nginx but that didn't help either.

Comment: "_it was not able to set the keys_"? Why is so? Do you actually mean that the caching on EC2 is disabled? In such case, just use Dummy Cache - it will work transparently as if nothing was saved in the cache.

Comment: @Tadeck I am on production server so I am not sure if using Dummy cache is a good idea

Comment: Are you sure the memcached port is accessible from your application/web server instance? Try 'telnet <cache-host> 11211' from your web intance.

Comment: @rhetonik I tried that, telnet works but when i do stats items it shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a silly glitch. I found out that i needed to reload gunicorn server to make the new middleware work. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a case of add this to your settings.py?

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-per-site-cache).

Only I'm not too clear what steps you mean when you say you 'added a new middleware'.

Comment: I added the middleware to settings.py That is why it is running on local machine as I mentioned so that is not the problem. I would like to point out site is using nginx and gunicorn as web servers so my query now boils down to is there a step that I am missing so that this new middleware gets called each time user does a specific task. I hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set caching in `CACHES` setting, taking into account all credentials needed to access the cache server: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached

Also make sure the cache server is accessible from the instance you are trying to use.

When it comes to using new middleware (a slightly different issue), then:

- make sure it is defined properly in the settings (not overwritten by other settings, like eg. commonly used `local_settings.py` file, which should be different depending on the environment you use),
- make sure middleware class is defined properly (defines eg. `process_request()`, if you want to do something for the incoming request),
- if you are using eg. mod_wsgi with Apache, remember to reload the service (in this case Apache), by eg. invoking `sudo service apache2 reload` (as in the mentioned case),

Comment: the site is using gunicorn and nginx as web servers. Do you think they need to be reloaded or something needs to be done there?